# Way to display pdf files in webpage that works in Internet Explorer with no add-ins

Tags: pdf-viewer, internet-explorer

A pdf file can show up in an iframe in Chrome, but not in IE.

we have no control over what the users of our public website have installed, 
and we can't ask them to install an add-in or configure their settings.

What we need is a server-end solution, that takes a pdf and renders it on the screen in ANY browser, including IE. I don't care if it renders the pdf as an image or as html or anything else for that matter, as long as it works.

It doesn't have to be free.

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

The chosen answer led me to discover [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/). Viewer js is based on pdf.js, but it has some limitations that its base does not have. I needed to load pdfs from other domains and also load base64 encoded pdf data. pdf.js enabled me to do that. The chosen answer led me in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you looking into a server side solution, why not use something like [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/examples/) which works on IE?

Comment: @Tom, by "server side", I just meant not the user's browser, so yes, this appears it would work. Can you add an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Sure thing, one moment please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ViewerJS is just what your looking for,

## [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) ([Open Source](https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS))

> ViewerJS must be the easiest way to use presentations, spreadsheets,
>   **PDF's** and other documents on your website or blog
>   without any external dependencies. No tricks, no conversions, no
>   unexpected downtime from external services, and no plugins required –
>   it happens to work just fine in all major browsers today from the
>   comfort of your own webserver. Free of cost, free as in open source
>   (so you can tweak it yourself) and very easy to use. Download and
>   unpack on your webserver and add one small text snippet to your
>   webpages. That is it: ViewerJS does the rest.

[image: ViewerJS with a PDF]